# how to check duplicate element values using xslt

Tags: xslt

```
    <BookList>
    <Book>
    <History>
    <Type>history</Type>
    <Prize>123</Prize>
    <Publication>``
    <Name>YEAP1</Name>
    </Publication>
    <RNumber Type="VolumeNumber">11111</RNumber>
    <RNumber Type="SupplementNumber">123456</RNumber>
    </History>
    <chemistry>
    <Type>chemistry</Type>
    <Prize>333</Prize>
    <Publication>
    <Name>YEAP</Name>
    </Publication>
    <RNumber Type="VolumeNumber">11111</RNumber>
    <RNumber Type="SupplementNumber">45454</RNumber>
    </chemistry>
                      ......

    </Book>
    </BookList>
```

There are duplicate VolumnNumber 11111. How to check duplicate VolumnNumber in BoolList xml using xslt . please help on this

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157705/checking-for-a-duplicate-element-in-the-output-using-xslt

Comment: Are you just trying to check to see if there is a duplicate?  What is the expected output supposed to look like? (ie, an html page that displays which volumes are duplicates?)

Comment: need to check is there any duplicate volumnnumber exist in xml or not

Answer (score 2):

**I. This can be found using a single XPath expression**:

```
    false()
   or
    /*/*/*/RNumber
           [@Type='VolumeNumber'
          and
            . = ../preceding-sibling::*
                   /RNumber[@Type='VolumeNumber']
            ]
```

**Here is a complete XSLT transformation that evaluates this XPath expression and outputs the result of this evaluation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  Duplicate volume numbers exist: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "false()
   or
    /*/*/*/RNumber
           [@Type='VolumeNumber'
          and
            . = ../preceding-sibling::*
                   /RNumber[@Type='VolumeNumber']
            ]
   "/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<BookList>
    <Book>
        <History>
            <Type>history</Type>
            <Prize>123</Prize>
            <Publication>``     
                <Name>YEAP1</Name>
            </Publication>
            <RNumber Type="VolumeNumber">11111</RNumber>
            <RNumber Type="SupplementNumber">123456</RNumber>
        </History>
        <chemistry>
            <Type>chemistry</Type>
            <Prize>333</Prize>
            <Publication>
                <Name>YEAP</Name>
            </Publication>
            <RNumber Type="VolumeNumber">11111</RNumber>
            <RNumber Type="SupplementNumber">45454</RNumber>
        </chemistry>
        ......      
    </Book>
</BookList>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
  Duplicate volume numbers exist: true
```

---

**II. Solution using keys (generally more efficient):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="kVolNum" match="RNumber[@Type='VolumeNumber']"
          use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  Duplicate volume numbers exist: <xsl:text/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "false()
   or
    /*/*/*/RNumber
            [@Type='VolumeNumber'
           and
             key('kVolNum',.)[2]
            ]"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
  Duplicate volume numbers exist: true
```

Comment: Long time since 2003/04/05 on XSL List - Just playing after a decade - If I wanted to check if there were any duplicates of `<string>com.text1.text2</string>` thru an XML file at any level, will this still work or should I post a fresh question?

Comment: E.g. Here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730689/find-matching-non-matching-elements-between-2-plist-xml-files