# Find matching & non matching elements between 2 plist XML files?

Tags: xml, xslt, match

Find matching & non matching elements between 2 plist XML files, throughout the files?

I have 2 .plist XML filed from iOS; just an FYI.

- What matters is figuring out which of items (Apps) exist in both files, and which ones do not.
- Since, they could exist in various places, in any order, at any level of the XML structure, a simple File Compare using Beyond Compare etc. would not work.

I've done quite a bit of XML/ XSLT code back when XSLT 2.0 was being worked and Saxon was the only compliant parser. I have Altova XML Spy, DiffDog on Win 8.1.

But, I'm open to figuring out what's missing on both sides/ each side and what's there in both, using a non XML/ XSL mechanism as well, if it's easier.

- Item Element is of this type: `<string>com.apple.MobileSMS</string>` and may exist at various places in the XML structure.

  - Exists as **App** under `<array>` to be counted for matching/ comparison
  - Can exist for **Folder Names**, under `<dict>` not to be counted for matching/ comparison
- More details about this specific .plist XML structure is outlined here: 
  http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/11704062690/springboard-icon-layouts-iconstateplist

> **SpringBoard Icon Layouts - IconState.plist**

I was looking for a way to get a list of all applications, that aren’t hidden (so excluding things like Web.app).
And although I found it ((NSArray*)[[SBIconModel sharedInstance] visibleIconIdentifiers]). I also found a dictionary SpringBoard keeps of the Icon layout.

Lets take a closer look at this:

- the dock icons are in a separate array for key ‘buttonBar’;
- the pages are in the array for key 'iconLists’;
- each page is a separate array in the iconLists array;
- in the array for each page the icons are string;
- the icons string is the apps displayId;
- a folder is an NSDictionary;
- each folder has these keys;

  - a displayName key which is a string, it’s name;
  - iconLists which is an array of icons like each pages (displayId strings);

---

```
<!-- language-all: lang-xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
 <all>
  <!-- Outer <dict> replaced by <all> -->
  <key>buttonBar</key>
  <array>
   <string>com.apple.MobileSMS</string>
   <string>com.apple.mobilemail</string>
   <string>com.apple.mobilesafari</string>
  </array>
  <key>iconLists</key>
  <pages>
   <!-- replaced by <pages> -->
   <page>
    <!-- replaced by <page> -->
    <string>com.apple.mobilephone</string>
    <string>com.apple.mobilecal</string>
    <string>com.apple.mobileslideshow</string>
    <string>com.apple.camera</string>
    <string>com.apple.videos</string>
    <string>com.apple.youtube</string>
    <string>com.apple.Maps</string>
    <string>com.apple.weather</string>
    <string>com.apple.mobilenotes</string>
    <string>com.apple.reminders</string>
    <string>com.apple.mobiletimer</string>
    <string>com.apple.gamecenter</string>
    <dict>
     <!-- Inner <dict> represents Folders -->
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Apple</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.apple.mobileme.fmf1</string>
       <string>com.apple.Cards</string>
       <string>com.apple.iBooks</string>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <string>com.apple.MobileStore</string>
    <string>com.apple.AppStore</string>
    <string>com.apple.Preferences</string>
   </page>
   <page>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Utilities</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.apple.MobileAddressBook</string>
       <string>com.apple.calculator</string>
       <string>com.apple.VoiceMemos</string>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Jailbreak</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.saurik.Cydia</string>
       <string>libactivator</string>
       <string>eu.heinelt.ifile</string>
       <string>crash-reporter</string>
       <string>com.googlecode.mobileterminal.Terminal</string>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Social</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.atebits.Tweetie2</string>
       <string>info.colloquy.mobile</string>
       <string>com.tapbots.Tweetbot</string>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Other</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.apple.stocks</string>
       <dict>
        <key>displayName</key>
        <string>Newsstand</string>
        <key>iconLists</key>
        <array/>
        <key>listType</key>
        <string>newsstand</string>
       </dict>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <string>com.clickgamer.AngryBirds</string>
    <string>com.apple.mobileipod</string>
   </page>
   <page>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Utilities</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.apple.MobileAddressBook</string>
       <string>com.apple.calculator</string>
       <string>com.apple.VoiceMemos</string>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Jailbreak</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.saurik.Cydia</string>
       <string>libactivator</string>
       <string>eu.heinelt.ifile</string>
       <string>crash-reporter</string>
       <string>com.googlecode.mobileterminal.Terminal</string>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Social</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.atebits.Tweetie2</string>
       <string>info.colloquy.mobile</string>
       <string>com.tapbots.Tweetbot</string>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
     <key>displayName</key>
     <string>Other</string>
     <key>iconLists</key>
     <array>
      <array>
       <string>com.apple.stocks</string>
       <dict>
        <key>displayName</key>
        <string>Newsstand</string>
        <key>iconLists</key>
        <array/>
        <key>listType</key>
        <string>newsstand</string>
       </dict>
      </array>
     </array>
     <key>listType</key>
     <string>folder</string>
    </dict>
    <string>com.clickgamer.AngryBirds</string>
    <string>com.apple.mobileipod</string>
   </page>
  </pages>
 </all>
</plist>
```

Comment: To restate the basic problem, you're hoping to get a list of `array/string` values that exist in both of two input files?  Or do you also need a list of `array/string` values that exist in only one of the two input files?

Comment: Also, please post what you have tried, and explain what's working and what isn't working.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - I'd like a to have a List of what's common, what's only in Left file and what's only on Right file. Preferably in easy to read tabular format

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - What I've tried so far, playing with XSL after 10+ years, so going in steps - Got some basics done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761829/present-springboard-plist-xml-in-proper-tabular-layout-with-correct-fields-cou

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments, it sounds like you need a table listing all the unique `string` values that are children of `array` elements and that appear in both files, including also a list of values unique to the first file and those unique to the second file.

Assuming you've loaded the two files into variables called `File1` and `File2`, you could generate the main full list using an XPath expression like:

```
distinct-values($File1//array/string | $File2//array/string)
```

To test for values unique to `File1`, where the context item `.` is one of the values in the main full list:

```
<xsl:if test=". = $File1//array/string and not(. = $File2//array/string)">
```

... and for values unique to `File2`:

```
<xsl:if test=". = $File2//array/string and not(. = $File1//array/string)">
```

This approach could be further refined, such as by sorting the list.  The above addresses the core of your needs.  From there, you can decide how you want to lay out the values, be it in an HTML table or some other structure.

Comment: @Eirkr Utlendi - Can you please help me with a little more code on the correct way to "Assuming you've loaded the two files into variables called File1 and File2, you could generate the main full list" Its been 10+ yrs since I played with XSLT. Using XML Spy 2013 for now.

Comment: Sorry I lost track and had to drop this experiment due to some life issues.